# connecting 3 one phase Generator to get three phases

Tags: generator

I have a big welder machine that needs around 26 kW and three phases. A generator for this power is a little bit expensive and take me a while to import one.
*When you are in a complicated situation always you think in stupid ideas and this is one:*
I was thinking what if I connect one single phase generator (10 kW than I can get quickly) for each machine phase, could this option works for my application?
Thank you in advance for your attention

[image]

Comment: No, this would not work. Your three machines would not be properly synchronized.

Comment: I suspect it could in theory be done if you modified the three generators to all be coupled so that they are forced to turn in sync, and then aligned them all at 120° offsets, but at that point you're probably looking at taking way longer and way more cost than just getting a 3φ generator in the first place. And you still wouldn't guarantee balanced output, that would just make the phase angles right.

Comment: Two solutions : money & time, spend the money and have it quick or wait for the cheaper one to arrive. Also, is the grid not possible...

Comment: Hi Frank, it probably depends on the exact welder. Some may just take the 3φ and rectify it to DC with no other control first. If so, 3φ is used solely because it standardly supplies more power. Others may actively rectify 3φ, which means the phase angles *do* matter, and attempting this will spell disaster. If you can get ahold of a schematic (or even detailed pictures of inside the welder), we might be able to discern this.

Comment: Thank you every boby, I think I have to make an insvest (money-time)